# Why text winces after end of function action in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I am using jQuery for various animated text effects. In particular I use function [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn). This effect works well. But there is strange behavior at the end of this action. The text winces immediately after the function executes. As if style font-weight changes at the end. But this is not the case and this style is not really used.

Here is my page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
   .fadeInEffect { display: none; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $('.fadeInEffect').fadeIn(1000)
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="fadeInEffect">
      My text
   </div>
</body>
<html>
```

I observed this phenomenon while using other jQuery-functions. How can this be fixed? Any ideas about it?

Comment: I don't see any "wincing" (whatever you might mean by that) using that code: http://jsbin.com/apumaw/1

Comment: It exists after end of function

Comment: @ Alex: Yes, I did read the question. Again: I'm not seeing anything. I've tried Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and (for reasons I won't go into it's what I have handy right now) IE7. I see nothing at the end of the effect on any of them.

Comment: As if `font-weight` style is changed from bold to normal. I use Chrome.

Comment: @ Alex: Again: Yes, I read the question. You don't have to keep repeating what's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known artifact of the [DX filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215.aspx) used to emulate opacity in Internet Explorer 8 or lower: [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/WhatIsClearType.mspx) is effectively disabled for the duration of the filter's effect.

To my knowledge, there is no workaround. You may want to use another effect on these browsers.

Comment: @undefined, it indeed looks like the same problem, but I don't think WebKit is using DX filters under the hood. Did you check if the artifacts persist even with ClearType disabled?

Comment: I haven't tested it on Windows, this happens on Mac, I should test it with _font smoothing_ option disabled, this doesn't happen using firefox, thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I use last (23.0.1271.97) version of Chrome... Indeed, in other browsers such effect I have not see.